# Render HTML tag based on a prop in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to render an HTML tag conditionally like the following:

```
import React, { PropsWithChildren, useState } from "react";

interface TextProps {
  variant:
    | "h1"
    | "h2"
    | "h3"
    | "h4"
    | "h5"
    | "h6"
    | "body"
    | "subtitle"
    | "caption"
    | "body2";
}

export const Text = ({ variant, children }: PropsWithChildren<TextProps>) => {
  if (variant.includes("h")) {
    const Tag = `h${variant[1]}`;
    return <Tag>{children}</Tag>;
  }
  return <p>{children}</p>;
};
```

I have looked at other SO posts and came to this solution which is almost perfect, the only thing that's wrong is this typescript error

`Type '{ children: ReactNode; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.` - The error is shown at the `<Tag>` tag.
What could I do about this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a basic type casting to tell typescript that Tag is an 'h1' tag, which would have the exact same set of props as the other `h` tags.

All the following examples on [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecAKUEYAzgOrAwAWAwlcADYAmUSAdnAL5wBmRIcAESt0MQQG4AUJOBsYSKD3RI4AFSQAPGIWIlckuHABuKKMBRyAXAcNwAPkKoBGQTcMPBVAEyvb9xwDMvrYeVAAswe6OAKyR-p4AbHEeAEYQTACeyUIkAK4pMJQMSNmCaChghRBspWmZPlKc0pqQsHBo1STw6lpOcAC8cAAUeCZmFljt9MysHJyWBESkFNR0jCzsADw92kskAHwAlAP7%20obAPMNj5nIAdF2mMOSUVEOegofHOG7tnd0oAHMBsZTDcYABtJwAXTgKD0nhcUj8rBguSgHG2gP2ODQ0w2bE4mwA9KosUiuDYUWiMWBsbj1rNCUTaY0pJIWtB4B02F01JoYABlADulFxwJGNmuEwWADVQRNMDZ6TN2JJ5otdCtaHjZtt%20TpSEcTmc4CQRTAxUM5eM5F8fuUSCoEYJrH4HU7vC77XCPUFXbZ3Y4Iv7DIHPLEQ%200fY4kpHDFT0XBNtawXSdewmSmJvtyYYmEglLkGDA43AEzS0wyM8SWTYmpw2Ry2tzeTsAJKXQYSwxSqxwLNyRWh9NsNULA3PVYjvVaCdG-qnb7nS5DH4D%20D9TeOFz2Oxr%20VyAZbzw%20Xf7m0b49UIJnvzro%20DTwRW%202e%20bx9UWIvwxvq9JGx2siSCoomyYHjAlYqgSxLrjmdaUsB1JJrSOIjkytYNpIQA) to show that they have no errors

```
export const Text = ({ variant, children }: PropsWithChildren<TextProps>) => {
  if (variant.startsWith("h")) {
    const Tag = variant[1] as 'h1';
    return <Tag>{children}</Tag>;
  }
  return <p>{children}</p>;
};
```

You could also explicitly set up the options that you want to check against in a switch statement:

```
export const Text = ({ variant: Variant, children }: PropsWithChildren<TextProps>) => {
  switch (Variant){
    case 'h1':
    case 'h2':
    case 'h3':
    case 'h4':
    case 'h5':
    case 'h6':
      return <Variant>{children}</Variant>;
    default:
      return <p>{children}</p>
  }
};
```

As long as you check to make sure each type you want to use is in there explicitly, TS will recognize it.

```
export const Text = ({
  variant: Variant,
  children
}: PropsWithChildren<TextProps>) => {
  if (
    Variant === "h1" ||
    Variant === "h2" ||
    Variant === "h3" ||
    Variant === "h4" ||
    Variant === "h5" ||
    Variant === "h6"
  ) {
    return <Variant>{children}</Variant>;
  }
  return <p>{children}</p>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define [custom type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to check if `variant` is a header tag:

```
type Header = 
    | "h1"
    | "h2"
    | "h3"
    | "h4"
    | "h5"
    | "h6";
  
interface TextProps {
  variant:
    | Header
    | "body"
    | "subtitle"
    | "caption"
    | "body2";
}

const isHeader = (variant: TextProps['variant']): variant is Header => variant.startsWith("h");

export const Text = ({ variant, children }: PropsWithChildren<TextProps>) => {
  if (isHeader(variant)) {
    const Tag = variant;
    return <Tag>{children}</Tag>;
  }
  return <p>{children}</p>;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecAKUEYAzgOrAwAWAwlcADYAmUSAdnAL5wBmRIcAESt0MQQG4AUDACeYJHAASqJkihwAvHElxdcAD5CqARkE69hwVQBMZvQaMBmOxaMAWF7stUArJ4dWAGwS5pLAbDBqPOgKACpIAB4whMQkuOYAbihQwCgRAFzmXkoqakUBAEYQTDL%20liQArhUwlAxIdUJoKGAtEGwdglU1tlKckpJofSTwwCTKKKrqWgAUWTl5MPlw8UkppADaAORruRGHALoAlFsnG3CzJQtqmgB8cLcRAHTT2TDklFRllZBJcpJJEpBYHBJmxpttEvAVngPlhofRmKwOJwtnt-tQ6IwWOwADw7ZJEUgvS6vdK6YA8ODLWbzRarbKnGCXak4cowuGxFAAc0073ZGyk9lYMAaUA4pKFLxwaHRRLYnGJAHoBYKXhKuOYpTK5WBFcrCZj1RqTaNxEA)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented using classnames

> TypographyType.ts

```
import { HTMLAttributes } from 'react';

export type TagType = 'h1' | 'h2' | 'h3' | 'h4' | 'h5' | 'h6' | 'p' | 'span';

export type HeadingType = HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>;
export type ParagraphType = HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>;
export type SpanType = HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>;

export type TypographyType = (HeadingType | ParagraphType | SpanType) & {
  variant?:
    | 'h1'
    | 'h2'
    | 'h3'
    | 'h4'
    | 'h5'
    | 'h6'
    | 'body1'
    | 'body2'
    | 'subtitle1'
    | 'subtitle2'
    | 'caption'
    | 'overline'
    | 'button';
};
```

> Typography.tsx

```
    import { FC } from 'react';
    import cn from 'classnames';
    import { typography } from '@/theme';
    
    import { TagType, TypographyType } from './TypographyType';
    
    const headings = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6'];
    const paragraphs = ['body1', 'body2', 'subtitle1', 'subtitle2'];
    const spans = ['button', 'caption', 'overline'];
    
    const Typography: FC<TypographyType> = ({
      children,
      variant = 'body1',
      className,
      ...props
    }) => {
      const { variants } = typography;
    
      const Tag = cn({
        [`${variant}`]: headings.includes(variant),
        [`p`]: paragraphs.includes(variant),
        [`span`]: spans.includes(variant)
      }) as TagType;
    
      return (
        <Tag
          {...props}
          className={cn(
            {
              [`${variants[variant]}`]: variant,
            },
            className
          )}
        >
          {children}
        </Tag>
      );
    };
    
    export default Typography;
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest, you take a look in to this: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement

```js
React.createElement('h1', {someProps: 42})
```